# Problem with python code for Keithley 2450, pymeasure "apply current" does not work

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a python program to communicate with my keithley2450 sourcemeter but I can't impose a current.
Let me explain I manage to communicate with the keithley2450, and I would like to impose a current for a period of time that I define and measure the resistance and the voltage.
But I can't impose a current.

```
from pymeasure.instruments.keithley import Keithley2450
import time

import openpyxl

t_acquisition  = 10  
tempsreel = 0

import pyvisa
rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()  
print(rm.list_resources())

wb = openpyxl.Workbook() 
sheet = wb.active

try:
    keithley = Keithley2450('USB0::0x05E6::0x2450::04490659::0::INSTR')
    keithley.apply_current()                # Sets up to source current
    keithley.source_current_range = 10e-3   # Sets the source current range to 10 mA
    keithley.compliance_voltage = 10        # Sets the compliance voltage to 10 V
    keithley.source_current = 0             # Sets the source current to 0 mA
    keithley.enable_source()                # Enables the source output
    keithley.measure_resistance()
    keithley.measure_voltage()
    keithley.ramp_to_current(5e-3)          # Ramps the current to 5 mA
    

except:
    raise ConnectionError("Unable to connect to the Keithley 2450.")


list_current = []
list_voltage = []
list_resistance = []
liste_temps_mesure = []
liste_temps = []

while int(tempsreel) < t_acquisition :
    #list_current.append(keithley.current)
    list_voltage.append(keithley.voltage)
    list_resistance.append(keithley.resistance)
    temps = time.time()
    liste_temps_mesure.append(temps)
    tempsreel = temps - liste_temps_mesure[0]
    liste_temps.append(tempsreel)
    print(f"{tempsreel}, {keithley.resistance}, {keithley.voltage}")

sheet['A'+str(1)].value = 'Temps (s)'
#sheet['B'+str(1)].value = 'Current (A)'
sheet['C'+str(1)].value = 'Voltage (V)'
sheet['D'+str(1)].value = 'Resistance'

for i in range(0,len(liste_temps)):
    sheet['A'+str(i+2)].value = liste_temps[i]
    #sheet['B'+str(i+2)].value = list_current[i]
    sheet['C'+str(i+2)].value = list_voltage[i]
    sheet['D'+str(i+2)].value = list_resistance[i]

wb.save('Data_sourcemetre.xlsx')
print('Data saved !')
```

Comment: can you add the outputs? also, try putting the compliance_voltage and current_range in the apply_current method https://pymeasure.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/instruments/keithley/keithley2450.html#pymeasure.instruments.keithley.Keithley2450.apply_current